# Flatten array with given depth

Tags: javascript, arrays

The problem is to create a function that flattens the given array up to the depth passed as an argument. Depth is basically how deep the array can be in the array. So the task is to create a function that looks like below:

```
function flatarray(arr, depth)
```

If the passed array is:

```
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7], 8], [10, 11, [12, [13]]], 9];
```

for depth = 1, it should return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11 , 12, 13, 9]. Here, as the depth is 1, so it will be fully flattened.

for depth = 2, it should return [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12, 13], 9]. Here, as the depth is 2, then array inside array should be flattened.

for depth = 3, it should return [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7], 8], [10, 11, [12, 13], 9]. And so on.

Comment: So what have you attempted?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: There's (recently) the built-in [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) (easily polyfilled), but the depth argument works the other way around.

Comment: @epascarello I have seen this. But, this is not what I want.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes.

Comment: Then your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. (Also: Mention your prior research in the question in the first place, including **why** previous things you've found won't work for you.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have tried many options using recursion. But, I am only able to flatten it completely. Depth is the tricky part where I am facing the issue. I will give it more tries and will see.

Answer (score 4):

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7], 8], [10, 11, [12, 13]], 9];

function flatten(arr, depth) {
  if (depth === 1) {
    return flattenArr(arr);
  }

  let res = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      res.push(flatten(arr[i], depth - 1));
    } else {
      res.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

function flattenArr(arr) {
  let res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      res = res.concat(flattenArr(arr[i]))
    } else {
      res.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(flatten(arr, 3));
```

I was able to do it. But, not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Posting this answer in case someone needs it in the future.

Comment: This is amazing. Even I tried to solve this but couldn't get it. Thank you for sharing this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Small edit I made in **sk01**'s answer (added **Default parameters and use let instead of var**)

> P.S.: I tried to edit **sk01**'s answer but it's showing me **" Suggested edit queue is full"** so I'm posting it as an answer

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7], 8], [10, 11, [12, 13]], 9];

function flatten(arr, depth = 1) {
  if (depth === 1) {
    return flattenArr(arr);
  }

  let res = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      res.push(flatten(arr[i], depth - 1));
    } else {
      res.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

function flattenArr(arr) {
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      res = res.concat(flattenArr(arr[i]))
    } else {
      res.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(flatten(arr, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
var flat = function (arr, n) {
if(n === 0) return arr;

let newArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(Array.isArray(arr[i])){
        newArray.push(...flat(arr[i], n-1));
    }else{
    newArray.push(arr[i]);

    }
}
return newArray;
```

`};`